# What does this function signature mean in sml?

Tags: function, sml, smlnj

I'm looking through some notes that my professor gave regarding the language SML and one of the functions looks like this:

```
fun max gt = 
    let fun lp curr [] = curr
           | lp curr (a::l) = if gt(a,curr)
                             then lp a l
                             else lp curr l
in
    lp
end
```

Could someone help explain what this is doing? The thing that I am most confused about is the line:

```
    let fun lp curr [] = curr
```

What exactly does this mean? As far as I can tell there is a function called `lp` but what does the `curr []` mean? Are these arguments? If so, aren't you only allowed one parameter in sml?

Comment: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall08/cos441/notes/lect-SMLNJ.pdf   That's a form of function definition you'll see over and over in ML-based languages, haskell, lisp: if you've hit empty list, the function is done, otherwise process head of list and recurse

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what parameters function `lp` takes and what `curr` is?  Is the parameter a tuple `(curr,someList)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that `lp` is a function that takes 2 parameters, the first being `curr` and the second being, well, a list, which logically, may be either empty (`[]`) or contain at least one element *(`(a::l)` is a pattern for a list where `a` is at the head, and the rest of the list is `l`)*.

If one were to translate that bit of FP code into a certain well-known imperative language, it would look like:

```
function lp(curr, lst) {
  if (lst.length == 0) {  
    return curr;
  } else {
    var a = lst[0];                   // first element
    var l = lst.slice(1, lst.length); // the rest
    if (gt(a, curr)) {
      return lp(a, l);
    } else {
      return lp(curr, l)
    }
  }
}
```

Quite a mouthful, but it's a faithful translation.

Functional languages are based on the [Lambda Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), where functions take exactly one value and return one result. While SML and other FP languages are based on this theory, it's rather inconvenient in practice, so many of these languages allow you to express passing multiple parameters to a function via what is known as [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

So yes, in ML functions actually take only one value, but currying lets you emulate multiple arguments.

Let's create a function called `add`, which adds 2 numbers:

```
fun add a b = a + b
```

should do it, but we defined 2 parameters. What's the type of `add`? If you take a look in the REPL, it is `val add = fn : int -> int -> int`. Which reads, *"add is a function that takes an int and returns another function (which takes an int and returns an int)"*

So we could also have defined `add` this way:

```
fun add a = 
  fn b => a + b
```

And you will see that they are alike. In fact it is safe to say that in a way,
the former is syntactic sugar for the later.
So all functions you define in ML, even those with several arguments, are actually functions with one argument, that return functions that accept the second argument and so on. It's a little hard to get used to at first but it
becomes second nature very soon.

```
fun add a b = a + b  (* add is of type  int -> int -> int *)

add 1 2 (* returns 3 as you expect *)

(* calling add with only one parameter *)

val add1 = add 1
```

What's `add1`? It is a *function* that will add `1` to the single argument you pass it!

```
add1 2 (* returns 3 *)
```

This is an example of *partial application*, where you are calling a function piecemeal, 
one argument at a time, getting back each time, another function that accepts the rest
of the arguments.

Also, there's another way to *give the appearance* of multiple arguments: tuples:

```
(1, 2);     (* evaluates to a tuple of (int,int) *)

fun add (a,b) = a + b;

add (1, 2)  (* passing a SINGLE argument to a function that
               expects only a single argument, a tuple of 2 numbers *)
```

In your question, `lp` *could have* also been implemented as `lp (curr, someList)`:

```
fun max gt curr lst = 
    let fun lp (curr, []) = curr
          | lp (curr, (a::l)) = if gt(a,curr) then lp (a, l)
                                else lp (curr, l)
in
    lp (curr, lst)
end
```

Note that in this case, we have to declare `max` as `max gt curr lst`!

In the code you posted, `lp` was clearly implemented with currying. And the type of
`max` itself was `fn: ('a * 'a -> bool) -> 'a -> 'a list -> 'a`. Taking that apart:

```
('a * 'a -> bool) ->  (* passed to 'max' as 'gt' *)   
    'a ->             (* passed to 'lp' as 'curr' *)
       'a list ->     (* passed to 'lp' as 'someList' *)
          'a          (* what 'lp' returns (same as what 'max' itself returns) *)
```

Note the *type* of `gt`, the first argument to `max`: `fn : (('a * 'a) -> bool)` - it is a function of **one** argument `('a * 'a)`, a tuple of two `'a`'s and it returns an `'a`. So no currying here.

Which to use is a matter of both taste, convention and practical considerations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it's not too much work, could you show me what `lp` would look like if it had been implemented as `lp (curr, someList)`? Thanks

Comment: In ML? Just added it. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Faiz "_In fact it is safe to say that in a way, the former is syntactic sugar for the later_". It is indeed a derived form, though the one you presented is not expanded all the way to its equivalent form.

Comment: Ah, you mean `val add = fn a => fn b => a + b`? Yes, I ought to have added that for completeness! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify a bit on currying, from Faiz's excellent answer.

As previously stated SML only allows functions to take 1 argument. The reason for this is because a function `fun foo x = x` is actually a derived form of (syntactic sugar) `val rec foo = fn x => x`. Well actually this is not entirely true, but lets keep it simple for a second

Now take for example this power function. Here we declare the function to "take two arguments"

```
fun pow n 0 = 1 
  | pow n k = n * pow n (k-1)
```

As stated above, `fun ...` was a derived form and thus the equivalent form of the power function is

```
val rec pow = fn n => fn k => ...
```

As you might see here, we have a problem expressing the two different pattern matches of the original function declaration, and thus we can't keep it "simple" anymore and the real equivalent form of a `fun` declaration is

```
val rec pow = fn n => fn k =>
    case (n, k) of 
      (n, 0) => 1
    | (n, k) => n * pow n (k-1)
```

For the sake of completeness, cases is actually also a derived form, with anonymous functions as the equivalent form

```
val rec pow = fn n => fn k => 
    (fn (n,0) => 1
      | (n,k) => n * pow n (k-1)) (n,k)
```

Note that `(n,k)` is applied directly to the inner most anonymous function.